# hadoop reducer not considering two equal custom writable objects as equal

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, writable

I am trying to write a map reduce program that checks for common friends.
I am using a custom writable (FriendPair) as key.

Given the following input

```
Tom Jerry,John
John Jerry,Sarah,Tom
```

It should output Jerry as the common friend for Tom and John

```
[John,Tom]    Jerry
[John,Sarah]    
[John,Jerry]
[Tom,Jerry]
```

Instead the map reduce is outputting the following

```
[John,Tom]  
[John,Sarah]    
[John,Jerry]    
[Tom,John]  
[Tom,Jerry]
```

The keys [John,Tom] and [Tom,John] are considered unequal.

Below is the code

**Custom Writable**

```
    public class FriendPair implements WritableComparable<FriendPair> {
        
        Text friend1;
        Text friend2;
        
        public FriendPair() {
            this.friend1 = new Text("");
            this.friend2 = new Text("");
        }
        
        public FriendPair(Text friend1, Text friend2) {
            this.friend1 = friend1;
            this.friend2 = friend2;
        }
        
        public Text getFriend1() {
            return friend1;
        }
        public void setFriend1(Text friend1) {
            this.friend1 = friend1;
        }
        public Text getFriend2() {
            return friend2;
        }
        public void setFriend2(Text friend2) {
            this.friend2 = friend2;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
            friend1.write(out);
            friend2.write(out);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
            friend1.readFields(in);
            friend2.readFields(in);
        }
    
        @Override
        public int compareTo(FriendPair pair2) {
            return ((friend1.compareTo(pair2.getFriend2()) == 0 && friend2.compareTo(pair2.getFriend1()) == 0)
                   || (friend1.compareTo(pair2.getFriend1()) == 0 && friend2.compareTo(pair2.getFriend2()) == 0)) ? 0 : -1;
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            FriendPair pair2 = (FriendPair) o;
            return (friend1.equals(pair2.getFriend2()) && friend2.equals(pair2.getFriend1()) 
                    || friend1.equals(pair2.getFriend1()) && friend2.equals(pair2.getFriend2()));
        }
        
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "[" + friend1 + "," + friend2 + "]";
        }
        
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return friend1.hashCode() + friend2.hashCode();
        }
    
    }
```

**Mapper**

```
public class MutualFriendsMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, FriendPair, Text> {

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        String line = value.toString();
        String[] items = line.split("\t");

        String name = items[0];
        String friendsList = items[1];
        String[] friends = friendsList.split(",");
        for (String friend : friends) {
            FriendPair fp = new FriendPair(new Text(name), new Text(friend));
            FriendPair fp2 = new FriendPair(new Text(friend), new Text(name));
            context.write(fp, new Text(friendsList));
        }
    }
}
```

**Reducer**

```
public class MutualFriendsReducer extends Reducer<FriendPair, Text, FriendPair, FriendArray> {

    @Override
    public void reduce(FriendPair key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        
        List<String> allFriends = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(Text value : values) {
            String[] valueArray = value.toString().split(",");
            allFriends.addAll(Arrays.asList(valueArray));
        }
        List<Text> commonFriends = new ArrayList<Text>();
        Set<String> uniqueFriendSet = new HashSet<String>(allFriends);
        for(String friend : uniqueFriendSet) {
            int frequency = Collections.frequency(allFriends, friend);
            if(frequency > 1) {
                commonFriends.add(new Text(friend));
            }
        }
        
        context.write(key, new FriendArray(Text.class, commonFriends.toArray(new Text[commonFriends.size()])));
    }
}
```

**FriendArray (Output)**

```
public class FriendArray extends ArrayWritable {

    public FriendArray(Class<? extends Writable> valueClass, Writable[] values) {
        super(valueClass, values);
    }
    
    public FriendArray(Class<? extends Writable> valueClass) {
        super(valueClass);
    }
    
    public FriendArray() {
        super(Text.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Text[] get() {
        return (Text[]) super.get();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void write(DataOutput data) throws IOException {
        for(Text t : get()) {
            t.write(data);
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        Text[] friendArray = Arrays.copyOf(get(), get().length, Text[].class);
        String print="";
        
        for(Text f : friendArray) 
            print+=f+",";
        
        return print;
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the "sort" stage Hadoop doesn't operate on java objects, but only their byte representation (the output of the `FriendPair.write()` method), thus it can't call `FriendPair.equals()`. So in order to make Hadoop understand that keys [John,Tom] and [Tom,John] are equal, you have to make sure that their `write` output is identical. One way to achieve this is to enforce the order of friends in the pair, for example sort them alphabetically (then both pairs would look [John,Tom]).

Comment: This worked, but I still don't understand why the compareTo method was not returning 0 when [Tom, John] and [John, Tom] pairs are equal. Shouldn't they be sent to the same reducer?

Comment: Well, you're partially right. They ARE sent to the same reducer instance, because they have the same hashcode. But the reducer sees them as different keys because their byte representation is different.